# Understanding 2^31 and -2^31 integer promotion

Tags: c++, c, implicit-conversion, integer-promotion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("sizeof(int): %zu\n", sizeof(int));
    printf("%d\n", 2147483648u > -2147483648);
    printf("%d\n", ((unsigned int)2147483648u) > ((int)-2147483648));
    printf("%d\n", 2147483648u != -2147483648);
    printf("%d\n", ((unsigned int)2147483648u) != ((int)-2147483648));
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code in both C and C++, on cygwin64 and an rhel6.4 machine with gcc 5.2.0 is:

```
sizeof(int): 4
1
0
1
0
```

According to "[Integer promotions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions)", `2147483648u` will be of type `unsigned int` (even without the `u` suffix) and `-2147483648` of type `int` (as usual). Why the different results with explicit casting?

According to the "[Usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions)", this paragraph applies:

> Otherwise, the signedness is different: If the operand with the
>   unsigned type has conversion rank greater or equal than the rank of
>   the type of the signed operand, then the operand with the signed type
>   is implicitly converted to the unsigned type

This means that the correct result is as if:

```
2147483648u > 2147483648u
2147483648u != 2147483648u
```

were performed, because in 32 bits, signed -2^31 and unsigned 2^31 have the same representation. In other words, the result with casting is correct. What is going on?

I have the feeling that somehow, a higher-rank integer promotion is applied without casting, so I'm getting e.g. a 64-bit signed promotion on both sides -- but why?

Both executables are compiled as 64-bit, can this play a role?

Comment: Please choose one of C and C++. These two languages are different and the answer might be different for both of them.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Isn't, in this case.

Comment: Also, which C standard are you compiling against? Handling of integer constants changed in C11.

Comment: @DevSolar Still, not a reason to accept a C/C++ question. Ask two questions if you want to have an explanation looked up in both standards.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I think this "they are different" on SO is going a bit too far in some places. This one, for example.

Comment: @DevSolar I'm not having this conservation again. It was decided on meta that you may not ask C/C++ questions except if the question is specifically about the difference or about the interaction between these two. End of discussions.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I have made multiply sure that the behavior is identical in both languages (and between individual standards that are in common usage today). It *belongs* in both categories.

Comment: @Irfy No, it doesn't. Please pick one. If I said “I made sure `1+1` does the same thing in languages x, y, and z so my question about `1+1` belongs to all of them” that would be just as wrong.

Comment: @Irfy Also: Even if the behaviour is equal, the reason why the behaviour is this way may not be and you cannot demand people to lookup answers in both standards.

Comment: And lastly, you haven't answered my question: What C standard are you compiling against? Because handing of integer constants changed in C11 and the answer will be different.

Comment: @FUZxxl: This discussion is really unnecessary. Also, the behavior is identical between `-std={c,gnu}++{98,03,11,14}` and `-std={c,gnu}{89/99/11}` with GCC 5.2.0 -- which I already implied in my previous comment. I'm out.

Comment: @FUZxxl: It's OK if you don't want to *have* the discussion, but please draw the line at telling people that something was "decided" on meta when it wasn't, at least not [the last time I looked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252430).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no negative integer constants. There are only positive ones with the unary `-` operator applied.

Since `2147483648 > INT_MAX`, that promotes `2147483648` to the next larger signed (because you did not append `u`) integer type, *before* the `-` is applied.

---

By the way, that is why `INT_MIN` is usually defined as `(-INT_MAX - 1)` in `<limits.h>`. ;-)

Comment: Wow, this never hit me in about 17 years of coding in c/c++ :-)

Comment: In *my* case, I'm lucky and that is the case. However win64's long is 4 bytes, so if i had that done with a VC compiler, it wouldn't have been the case.

Comment: If you're trying to hit a limit, try entering -2^63 and -2^127 (computed) as a literal :)

Comment: @lrfy: With `(-LLONG_MAX - 1)`, the former is (comparatively) easy. The latter, to my knowledge, doesn't work without using multiplication of smaller-width constants or bit shifting. GCC supports `__int128_t`, but not the integer constant widths to go with it.